# UNO Material BottomNavigationBar Event Handler

Tags: material-ui, material-design, uno-platform

I am implementing the BottomNavigationBar from Uno.Material in my app.  I can get the bar to appear like I want it to- but can not figure out what the event handler is for when I click on a bottomnavigationbaritem to change it.  I have tried ItemInvoked, OnPressed, OnTouch, OnClick, Clicked- but not able to get it to work. I am a bit embarrassed to ask- but would someone be able to point me in the right direction of what event is fired and what the method signature of the event should be?

...
<controls:BottomNavigationBar x:Name="BottomNavBar" Grid.Row="2"mOnClick="BottomNavView_ItemInvoked">
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BottomNavigationBar` does not expose an `ItemInvoked` event. You can retrieve the current selection via the `SelectedItem` property. I suppose it could also offer a `ItemInvoked` option like `NavigationView` is offering, feel free to open an issue [here](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Material/issues) with your suggestion.

However, `BottomNavigationBarItem` is a `ToggleButton`, so it implements the `Click`, `Checked` and `Unchecked` events already.

Here's an example of how you could handle those events in your app. (You probably only need `Checked`, depending on your scenario)

```xml
<controls:BottomNavigationBar>
    <controls:BottomNavigationBar.Items>

        <controls:BottomNavigationBarItem Label="Favorites"
                                          Click="OnClick"
                                          Checked="OnChecked"
                                          Unchecked="OnUnChecked">
            <controls:BottomNavigationBarItem.Icon>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Favorite" />
            </controls:BottomNavigationBarItem.Icon>
        </controls:BottomNavigationBarItem>
[...insert more items...]
    </controls:BottomNavigationBar.Items>
</controls:BottomNavigationBar>
```

```cs
public void OnClick(object sender, object args)
{
    var navBarItem = sender as BottomNavigationBarItem;

    // Add logic here
}

public void OnChecked(object sender, object args)
{
    var navBarItem = sender as BottomNavigationBarItem;

    // Add logic here
}

public void OnUnChecked(object sender, object args)
{
    // Items are automatically unchecked when another one is checked.
    var navBarItem = sender as BottomNavigationBarItem;

    // Add logic here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Once you explained that each item is a togglebutton, it was much clearer.  You were right- I was able to do this with just the Click method.  I really appreciate how quickly you answered my question- and your explanation was exactly what I needed.  It was extremely clear and helpful.  Thank you.